# Exclude blank records using the sp_MSforeachdb and how to order DBName in ASC

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am needing to find where we have a SQL Server (DBSQLSERVER) defined in the databases in this server that I'm working in.  I was able to find an old post in another site to do this however had a couple of issues to remedy.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @text = @@SERVERNAME;
SET @sql = 
    'USE [?]
    SELECT ''?'' [DBName], @@SERVERNAME AS [Server], o.name AS [ObjName], o.type_desc [TypeDesc]
    FROM sys.sql_modules m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
    ON m.object_id = o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like ' + CHAR(39) + '%' + @text + '%' + CHAR(39) + '
    ORDER BY 1, 3 asc'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql;
```

I have 2 issues:

1. I am getting some BLANK RECORDS and don't understand where I'm picking that up.  Where are these coming from and HOW to exclude them from my record set would be appreciated.
2. In this SQL statement I am trying to create an ORDER BY statement but it is NOT working.  I have a sporatic order that I cannot define.  How can I put these in order of the DBNAME first then ObjName?

Please see pic for order problem.

Any help/direction on these 2 issues would be greatly appreciated.

[image: sp_MSforeachdb_order_problem]

Thanks.

Comment: The empty results sets are from databases that don't have an object that matches your where predicate. As for ordering, you have to remember that you are using a cursor here to scroll through each database. This isn't something you can control. However in your query you have an order by. I would highly recommend you order by column name instead of ordinal position. Its usage is deprecated and it is challenging to use from a number of perspectives.

Comment: `sp_MSforeachdb` does not return a single record set.  It returns one record set *for each database*.  Since an empty record set is a valid record set, databases which return no results still show a "blank" record.  This also answers why your results aren't ordered.  They *are* ordered *within each record set*.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the replies.  Bacon Bits - thanks for the clear and concise explanation as that really helped.  Is there a way to prevent the EMPTY record sets from being displayed?  Thanks again.

Comment: You can't just hide the empty result sets. Think about what is happening here. You are executing a query against each database. That query is going to execute and be a resultset even if there are no rows. You could create a temp table to hold the results of each select and make your dynamic sql insert into that temp table. That way you wouldn't get a row when there are no rows to be returned.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Appreciate the reply and the explanation.